# Angular template-driven form-validation using a directive

Tags: angular

I've been checking out the form validation fundamentals [at the official docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) and I can't wrap my head around with one of the examples.

Some background:

> In this sample, the forbidden name is "bob", so the validator will
>   reject any hero name containing "bob". Elsewhere it could reject
>   "alice" or any name that the configuring regular expression matches.

And here is the input element:

```
<input id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
   required minlength="4" forbiddenName="bob"
   [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel" >
```

Yet, the input from their example seems to be not validated:

[image]

while the input using reactive forms from the same example gets validated as expected:

[image]

How do I make template-driven form display the alert as seen in reactive form?

Here is the example from the official docs: https://stackblitz.com/angular/byyynkdrode

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Must be

```
<input id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
               required minlength="4" appForbiddenName forbiddenName="bob"
               [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel" >
```

or

```
<input id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
               required minlength="4" appForbiddenName [forbiddenName]="'bob'"
               [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel" >
```

See that the directive name is "appForbiddenName" and the @Input variable is "forbiddenName". Of course you can change the directive, and make that name of the selector was the same that the @Input

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[forbiddenName]', //<--forbiddenName, NOT appforbiddenName
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: ForbiddenValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class ForbiddenValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  @Input() forbiddenName: string; //<--see that the input variable is the same
                                  //that the selector of the directive
  ....
}
```

Comment: Figured it out 5mins ago and I was about to answer it on my own. Thanks